# Nested Routes in React not rendering correctly with react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my root component main switch like this

```js
<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <HashRouter history={history} >
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
        <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" component={Register}/>
        <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" component={Page404}/>
        <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" component={Page500}/>
        <Route path="/Console" name="Console" component={Console}/>
        <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
```

And inside the `Console` component I have another switch defined like this

```js
<main className="container">
  <div className="">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/Create" name="Create Park" component={CreateNew} />
      <Route path="/" name="Console" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</main>
```

When I visit `/Console` `HomePage` component shows properly.

But the when I visit `/Console/Create` `CreateNew` component would not show but instead shows `HomePage` component.

What I am doing wrong here ? What should I do to show `CreateNew` component at `/Console/Create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested Routes must have an absolute path specified, You can use `match.path` as a prefix to the nested Route to provide the path as an absolute one

```
<main className="container">
  <div className="">
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/Create`} name="Create Park" component={CreateNew} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/`} name="Console" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</main>
```

or else specify the complete path

```
<main className="container">
  <div className="">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/Console/Create" name="Create Park" component={CreateNew} />
      <Route path="/Console/" name="Console" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</main>
```

According to React-Router `match` documentation:

> A match object contains information about how a  matched
>   the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> `params - (object)` Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding
>   to the dynamic segments of the path
>
> `isExact - (boolean)` true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing
>   characters)
>
> `path - (string)` The path pattern used to match. Useful for building
>   nested s
>
> `url - (string)` The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building
>   nested s

Answer (score 0):

the Console component is refactored as following:

```
<main className="container">
      <div className="">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact  path="/" name="Console" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact  path="/Create" name="Create Park" component={CreateNew} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
 </main>
```